# Error message when installing Hg

Tags: mercurial, homebrew

I've been trying to download Mercurial, using the following code:

```
brew install hg
```

However, I keep coming across the same error message.

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/CarbonCore.h:47:10: fatal error: 'CarbonCore/TextCommon.h' file not found
#include <CarbonCore/TextCommon.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

I'm very new to this, so I'm unsure what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: Please run `brew doctor`; fix all the issues it mentions; then try again.

Comment: Update your xcode to the latest.